# What is a high impedance low level signal?

Tags: impedance

What is a high impedance low level signal?

(I'm reading the circuit designer's companion by Peter Wilson)

Comment: Low-lever means of small amplitude, so a little signal (little compared to other signals in that system or domain).  High impedance means that the signal is being driven by a source with a high Thevenin equivalent resistance; i.e. a source that will easily allow it's voltage to change when some external disturbance is imposed on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a weak signal.

*High impedance* means that the device or circuit that outputs the signal has a high [output impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_impedance). In simplified terms you could think of it as a high value resistor in series with the signal output (or the signal being sent over a long and thin wire). In real life there will also be some [reactance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance) and nonlinearity.

*Low level* in this context simply means that the signal has a low [amplitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude). This could be a result of the high impedance signal being fed into a low impedence input, but the way it's phrased, I think it's more likely to be an intrinsic property of the signal in question.

Comment: A good example would be the output of a pH electrode.